# How to put Parameter only with Javascript through URL in the website

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, getelementsbyclassname, setattribute

I am using the software rimacon.
And i am using this URL: http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker

[image: the serial-number shall be insert in this input, look in the mask red]

I want to send the Value of the serial number from Javascript (rimacon) into this input  of this website: (see picture)

In this website, i click the mouse on the right and click "inspect Element/ Element Untersuchen". I get this HTML-Code:

```
<input type="text" class="serial-number">
```

i would like to change this into:

```
<input type="text" class="serial-number" value="xXx">
```

then i write URL like:

```
http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker/?xXx="0QYG06DF3FA"
```

or i would like to change this CODE into:

```
<input type="text" class="serial-number" name="PUT-Serial-number">
```

then i write URL like:

```
http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker/?PUT-Serial-number="0QYG06DF3FA"
```

i tried some Code with setAttribute or createAttribute and so on to get this fixed:

for example:

```
//var x = document.getElementsByClassName("serial-number").href="http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker";

var x = document.querySelectorAll("input.serial-number[href^='http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker']");


var y = x.innerHTML = "value="+seriennummer;

alert("y:  "+y);
alert("Länge :  "+y.length);


//var attr = document.createAttribute("Value");
//attr.value=seriennummer;

//var attr = x.setAttribute("Value",seriennummer);

//alert("attr:  "+attr.value);

// this shall open window and show the serialnumber in this websites
url = escape("http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker");
var hpwindow = window.open("http://xxx:8081/sprungxbrett.php?TARGET="+url);  
hpwindow.focus();
```

This Code is in function of onclick().

Please I need your Help! Is there some way to get fixed this JS-Code!

Because in "Inspect element/Element Untersuchen", you can add Attribute Value into this

```
<input type="text" class="serial-number" value="0QYG06DF3FA">
```

then this serial number truly display in the input this website.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you could add it to localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage & see also sessionStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage or use cookies.

Comment: Hello admcfajn, thx for reply. I tried with simple test to get the variable from this  website http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker, even i used localstorage or sessionstorage. it shows everything  zero. the most problem i think is there `document.querySelectorAll("input.serial-number[href^='http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker']")`. Cause the query don't have access in this website.

Comment: Maybe you'll have an easier time with this: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 0):

this should solve getting the URL params as JSON format (wont show anything here, try any test file with url params, ex: test.html?this=that&that=this)

```html
<p id="result"> result: </p>

<script>
function getUrlVars() {
 var map = {};
 var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
  map[key] = value;
 });
  
  //get your values as JSON, one of the following
 console.log(map);
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(map);
 return map;
  
}

getUrlVars()
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Mohamad, thx for reply. I tried with your test. This URL http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker was putted in getUrlVars(). It shows empty. Cause all the parameter in this websites are hidden.